# Java - recieving input in loop

Tags: java, loops, 3d, render, lwjgl

I use LWJGL for 3d graphics.

The thing i want to do is to change render type from "GL_TRIANGLES" to "GL_LINES" by pressing a specified key (For example - F1).
Because of a high framerate normal

```
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(key))
        {
            //Action
        }
```

would switch on and off up to 200 times during normal button press.
Overall, its interesting to me, how this problem is usually solved, and whats the best way to deal with it.

So the thing i came up with is (Probably, very ineffective):

```
//Render class init
Key F1 = new Key(Keyboard.KEY_F1);

//Render method
renderMode = F1.ifPressed(delta);
if(renderMode)
{
    //GL_LINES render
}
else
{
    //GL_TRIANGLES render
}

//Key class
public class Key 
{
    int DELAY_TIME = 20;
    int delay = 0;
    int key;
    boolean isActive = false;
    boolean  state = false;

public Key(int key)
{
    this.key = key;
}

public boolean ifPressed(int delta)
{
    if(!isActive)
    {
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(key))
        {
            isActive = true;
            state = !state;
            return state;
        }
    }
    else if(delay <= DELAY_TIME * delta)
    {
        delay++;
    }
    else if(delay > DELAY_TIME)
    {
        delay = 0;
        isActive = false;
    }
    return state;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One general solution is to have a list of currently active actions / pressed keys. When an input event `PRESSED` is fired (this is typically done by the framework / OS) for some key, you check if that key is in the list.

```
if (list.contains(key)) {
    // not first time, so fire held
    onKeyHeld(key);
}
else {
    list.add(key);
    onKeyPressed(key);
}
```

When an input event `RELEASED` is fired, you do the following:

```
list.remove(key);
onKeyReleased(key);
```

Mouse events are done in a similar way.

Better still you can replace those methods with some `UserAction` class, so that it can be bound to keys / mouse events. The code would change to something like:

```
bind(Key.SPACE, new UserAction("Jump") {
    public void onActionStart() {} // on key pressed
    public void onAction() {}      // on key held
    public void onActionEnd() {}   // on key released
});
```

I have used this solution in a game library and therefore can confirm that it works.

Comment: I can confrm this is the best approach to deal with button events. This also works for mousebutton or gamepad button.

Comment: I still cannot understand what is the point of UserAction class. Could you please update the answer with some more implementation of it?

Comment: You don't have to have it, it just makes code less cluttered and more OO. It also helps separating 1 action from another, so it can be bound to a key or mouse event. Please see implementation here: https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL/blob/master/src/com/almasb/fxgl/event/UserAction.java and https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL/blob/master/src/com/almasb/fxgl/event/InputManager.java